# Are there security issues I should take into consideration if my shopping cart opens up a HTML invoice?

Tags: javascript, e-commerce, shopping-cart

To save on transaction costs when a user selects "buy now", an HTML invoice opens in a new tab with their order and our banking details for them to make a manual EFT. Are there security concerns I should be aware of? Could a hacker inject their own banking details into this? Suggestions to make it more secure?

I haven't built the `.js` script yet to inject the info into the invoice but here is the invoice code:

```
<header>
  <h1>Invoice</h1>
  <address>
    <p>Jonathan Neal</p>
    <p>101 E. Chapman Ave<br>Orange, CA 92866</p>
    <p>(800) 555-1234</p>
  </address>
  <span><img alt="" src="img/invoice-logo.png"><input type="file" accept="image/*"></span>
</header>
<article>
  <h1>Recipient</h1>
  <address>
    <p>Some Company<br>c/o Some Guy</p>
  </address>
  <table class="meta">
    <tr>
      <th><span>Invoice #</span></th>
      <td><span>101138</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th><span>Date</span></th>
      <td><span>January 1, 2012</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th><span>Amount Due</span></th>
      <td><span id="prefix">$</span><span>600.00</span></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <table class="inventory">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th><span>Item</span></th>
        <th><span>Description</span></th>
        <th><span>Rate</span></th>
        <th><span>Quantity</span></th>
        <th><span>Price</span></th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td><span>Front End Consultation</span></td>
        <td><span>Experience Review</span></td>
        <td><span data-prefix>$</span><span>150.00</span></td>
        <td><span>4</span></td>
        <td><span data-prefix>$</span><span>600.00</span></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <table class="balance">
    <tr>
      <th><span>Total</span></th>
      <td><span data-prefix>$</span><span>600.00</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th><span>Amount Paid</span></th>
      <td><span data-prefix>$</span><span>0.00</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th><span>Balance Due</span></th>
      <td><span data-prefix>$</span><span>600.00</span></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</article>
<aside>
  <h1><span>Additional Notes</span></h1>
  <div>
    <p>A finance charge of 1.5% will be made on unpaid balances after 30 days.</p>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you use proper TLS I would not worry much about MITM. If you don't - start using it now.

Also - I will assume that you generate the invoice server side. Or at least get the invoice data from the server. But client side in general is not safe.

Make sure the invoice is only available when the user is logged in. Or - of you allow shopping without logging in - make the invoice URL **hard** to guess. There is a great potential of customer data leaking in such a system.